# Does each Java function end with a native method?

Tags: java

I back traced the calling paths of Java API functions and finally ended with native methods.

Does each and every java-api function end with a native method?

Answer (score 9):

If you're talking about the core classes, like java.lang.System, java.io.File, java.net.Socket, etc, then yes, many of them "end" with a call to native code because those are the classes that "bind" to all the various platforms that Java runs on, and that native code is what hides the differences and allows Java code to run the same on every platform. However, for every method that ends with a native call, there are probably a million out there that don't, so the answer to your question is "no".

Answer (score 0):

No, some are solely java. Look at the source.

Comment: Actually, the **vast majority** of classes in the Java class libraries are implemented in Java

Answer (score 0):

Don't take it otherwise, may be you are misunderstanding something. May be you ended with class files because you do not have the source.